# maven jetty error 'Config error at <Set name="ThreadPool">'

Tags: java, maven, configuration, jetty

I'm trying to configure a jetty-servlet in java using maven.  I've create a jetty.xml file with the following entries

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE Configure PUBLIC "-//Jetty//Configure//EN" "http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/configure.dtd">
<Configure id="Server" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server">
  <Set name="ThreadPool">
    <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool">
      <Set name="minThreads">10</Set>
      <Set name="maxThreads">200</Set>
      <Set name="detailedDump">false</Set>
    </New>
</Set>
</Configure>
```

upon running the server

```
mvn jetty:run
```

I see the error

```
[WARNING] Config error at <Set name="ThreadPool">
<New class="org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool"><Set 
  name="minThreads">10</Set><Set name="maxThreads">200</Set><Set 
  name="detailedDump">false</Set></New>
</Set>
```

but cannot figure out what the problem actually is.  I've also included jetty-util as a dependency in the pom.xml file.  I'm using jetty version 9.4.12.v20180830 and java 8.  Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

`ThreadPool` is a constructor argument for `Server`.

See: Javadoc for [`org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server`](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/javadoc/9.4.12.v20180830/org/eclipse/jetty/server/Server.html#Server-org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ThreadPool-)

It's not a field and/or setter on Server, so you cannot use the `<Set name="ThreadPool">` syntax.

Instead of replacing the threadpool, just "Get" the existing one and change settings on it.

Eg:

```xml
<Get name="ThreadPool">
  <Set name="minThreads" type="int">10</Set>
  <Set name="maxThreads" type="int">200</Set>
  <Set name="detailedDump">false</Set>
</Get>
```